# SQL Server selecting with self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that has records like this:

```
FieldId  collationid  Type    Message 
---------------------------------------------
1         1234         WC     hello  
2         1234         WR     next message
3         1234         WZ     again  
4         1234         WX     another message 
5         ab12         WC     this message 
6         ab12         WR     again  
7         ab12         WZ     misc message 
8         5678         WC     hello  
9         5678         WR     next message  
10        5678         WZ     again  
11        5678         WX     another message
```

A recordset is complete when it has all four records, a WC, WR, WZ and WX.  I need a sql that shows me when a record is missing.  In the previous table example, the SQL would produce **ab12** because it only has WC, WR and WZ records.

Appreciate any help you can give me..

Answer (score 3):

Use `COUNT()` and `HAVING` :

```
SELECT collationid
FROM tbl
WHERE Type IN('WC', 'WR', 'WZ', 'WX')
GROUP BY collationid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Type) < 4
```

Comment: You have really fast fingers ;-) This would be my suggested answer as well. Upvoting...